# Get relation between Hosts and Datastores using vSphere Automation REST API

Tags: rest, vmware, vsphere

I'm trying to create VM using vSphere Automation SDK REST API and vRealize Orchestrator but the workflow in Orchestrator I'm using needs the host and datastore on which to create the VM (I'm cloning a VM using a template).

My problem is that my datastores are not shared by all clusters (and hosts) so I need to be careful to create a VM with a matching host and datastore.

With the vSphere Automation SDK REST API I can easily get the list of hosts and datastores (here's the doc I found : https://code.vmware.com/doc/preview?id=4645), but none of the "list" or "get" requests give me links between hosts and datastores.

How can I get the relations between my datastores and my hosts so that I can call Orchestrator with the correct parameters ?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: no I didn't get any answer, "luckily" the project was abandoned...

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://github.com/doublecloudinc/vim-rest-api
The REST APIs supports FULL features of vSphere APIs, and scales across many vCenter/ESXi servers. You can list all the host and pick one to get its datastore property easily with a couple of REST calls.

Also, vBrownBag tech talk: https://youtu.be/EpMlP27gEEM

Disclaimer: I am the creator of the REST APIs.